# How can I return the contents of cell(s) that occur in two cell ranges (concatenating if multiple matches occur)?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following spreadsheet and need to be able to check if a cell (or multiple cells) occur in two cell ranges.

For example, I would like to check if any cells in H2:H5 also occur in B8:F8 and if so, I would like to display the contents of the matching cells in cell H8. Furthermore, if more than one match occurs, I would like the contents of each matching cell to be **joined** and displayed in H8. So in this instance as there is only one match, 'CH (Phys)' would be placed in H8.

I then need to be able to reuse that formula / vba code to enable the same function for all cells from H8:Q17 to complete the conflict matrix.

Thank you for your time and help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the count,Use SUMPRODUCT/MATCH()

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B8:$G8<>"")*(ISNUMBER(MATCH($B8:$G8,H$2:H$7,0))))
```

If a match is found the MATCH will return a number.  If not found it will return an error.  The SUMPRODUCT then counts the number of time it is a number.

Put that in H8, copy over and down.

[image]

---

To place the values that match we need TEXTJOIN as an array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(($B8:$G8<>"")*(ISNUMBER(MATCH($B8:$G8,H$2:H$7,0))),$B8:$G8,""))
```

Depending on one's version this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: This is fantastic! Thank you so much and thanks for being so quick with your reply!

Comment: Is there a way to display the contents of the cell(s) that match instead of the total number of matches?

Comment: Sorry I misread, do you have TEXTJOIN()?

Comment: @sw123456 see edit.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! This is exactly what I needed! I really appreciate your time and support!